# нужно сделать так, что бы расчет выполнялся только до одного варианта, я написала, но не понимаю что я делаю не так

Tags: python

```
A = float(input('Введите A - '))
B = float(input('Введите B - '))
C = float(input('Введите C - '))
if D<0:
D = B ** 2-4 * A * C
E = D ** (1 / 2)
print("решения нет")
F = (-B + E) / (2*A)
G = (-B - E) / (2*A)
else:
 if F == G :
    print ("решение есть", F)
 else :
    print (F, G)
```

Comment: "что бы расчет выполнялся только до одного варианта" - что это значит?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
A = float(input('Введите A - '))
B = float(input('Введите B - '))
C = float(input('Введите C - '))
D = B**2 - 4 * A * C
if D < 0:
    print("решения нет")
else:
    E = D ** (1 / 2)
    F = (-B + E) / (2*A)
    G = (-B - E) / (2*A)
    if F == G :
        print ("решение есть", F)
    else :
        print (F, G)
```